# Codeigniter with CDN

Tags: php, codeigniter, cdn

I setup a website using a cms written with codeigniter,
after completed the website, I would like to move all the asset to a cdn.

all the asset links are in absolute path
i.e. /image/logo.png, /css/index.css, /video/promo.mp4

Can I route all these asset to a cdn without changing the html

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*(can't help as this has been voted down; I guess your question did not apply to the logic, or best practice)*

Basically you can't simple change that, as CDN use different Domain/Subdomin, naming convention and structure altogether.

But, you can try this;

- Assuming that your web server can use `.htaccess`, and
- Assuming the CDN will have the same folder structure, and name.

:: Try to redirect all images/resources request to the CDN.

```
RewriteRule ([^.]+\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|mp4|css|js))$ http://www.cdn-url.com/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: yes, I also aware it is not the best practice, just a short term solution for the impatient boss.

Comment: CDN use different Domain/Subdomin, naming convention and structure altogether. So?